# How to use SQL Server openrowset and Cross Apply to get an XML Attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, cross-apply

How do I get the value of an XML Attribute from XML that has been read from a file in SQL Server? I am able to read values from XML elements but not the attribute for an XML element. Below is the XML I am using. I would like to read the BuildingCode attribute from the Applicants element.

**XML in an external file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Applicants BuildingCode="7578">
    <SubCode>2000</SubCode>
      <Applicant>
        <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
        <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
        <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <LastName>Stewart</LastName>
        <StudentID>301</StudentID>
        <Membership>Gold</Membership>
      </Applicant>
      <Applicant>
        <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
        <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
        <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
        <FirstName>Sandy</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gomez</LastName>
        <StudentID>302</StudentID>
        <Membership>Bronze</Membership>
      </Applicant>
  </Applicants>
</Root>
```

**SQL to read the XML File and display the values in rows:**

```
SELECT 
   x1.Applicant.value('(../../@BuildingCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(../SubCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') as SubCode,
   x1.Applicant.value('(CourseName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as CourseName,
   x1.Applicant.value('(CourseCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as CourseCode,
   x1.Applicant.value('(StartDate/text())[1]', 'datetime') as StartDate,
   x1.Applicant.value('(FirstName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as FirstName,
   x1.Applicant.value('(LastName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as LastName,
   x1.Applicant.value('(StudentID/text())[1]', 'int') as StudentID,
   x1.Applicant.value('(Membership/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Membership

FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\FilesForTesting\XmlLoadTest101.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T1(BinaryData)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(T1.BinaryData AS xml)
) ) AS T2(XMLFromFile)

CROSS APPLY T2.XMLFromFile.nodes('Root/Applicants/Applicant') AS x1(Applicant);
```

The SQL works if I comment out the first select column which tries to read the BuildingCode attribute from the Applicants element.  I tried to navigate back up from the /Applicant element to get it but my attempt does not work.  I am using an @ symbol in front of the BuildingCode because I saw other internet samples doing this when trying to get the attribute of an element but again it does not work for me in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first descend to the `Applicants` node, then feed that into another `.nodes` call to get the `Applicant` nodes

```sql
SELECT
   x1.Applicants.value('@BuildingCode', 'VARCHAR(15)'),
   x1.Applicants.value('(SubCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)') as SubCode,
   x2.Applicant.value('(CourseName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as CourseName,
   x2.Applicant.value('(CourseCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as CourseCode,
   x2.Applicant.value('(StartDate/text())[1]', 'datetime') as StartDate,
   x2.Applicant.value('(FirstName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as FirstName,
   x2.Applicant.value('(LastName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as LastName,
   x2.Applicant.value('(StudentID/text())[1]', 'int') as StudentID,
   x2.Applicant.value('(Membership/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Membership

FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\FilesForTesting\XmlLoadTest101.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T1(BinaryData)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(T1.BinaryData AS xml)
) ) AS T2(XMLFromFile)

CROSS APPLY T2.XMLFromFile.nodes('Root/Applicants') AS x1(Applicants)
CROSS APPLY x1.Applicants.nodes('Applicant') AS x2(Applicant);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e468c3d7b539516f6b619e9dbff1a5e)